# is there a way to force the instance on oracle scheduler chain job in RAC

Tags: oracle, scheduler, oracle12c

We have a requirement to create an Oracle Scheduler-chain job in RAC environment. Is there a way to force all the steps in chain to be run on one instance?

We tried setting up the attributes like instance id to 1 but that didn't help as step 1 in chain ran on instance 1 and rest of the steps ran on 2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use v$Instance to identify your current instance

```
DECLARE
  pCurInstance varchar2(20);
BEGIN
  SELECT INSTANCE_NAME into pCurInstance FROM V$INSTANCE;
  IF (pCurInstance != "myInstance") THEN
    RETURN;
  END;

  --EXECUTE YOUR SCRIPT / FUNCTION / PROCEDURE HERE
END;
```

alternatively, more elegant way

```
svrctl add service -d <db_unique_name> -s AQ_01 -r <preferredinstance> -a <availableinstances>
dbms_scheduler.create_job_class(job_class_name=> 'AQ01', service=> 'AQ_01');
dbms_scheduler_create_job (job_name => v_jobname. . .
   job_class => 'AQ_01')
```

Comment: Thank you simonare... will try defining the job class and see how it goes. Thanks for input, will let you know.